# My Game's Infinite Platform Generation does Not Work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have followed a YouTube tutorial on how to make a doodle jump replica in 5 minutes.

The problem is, this tutorial is rushed and does not provide all the information needed and thus I have encountered one big problem.
The infinite random platform generation keeps skewing off to either the left or right side of the screen after a certain point, and I have no clue as to why.

Here is the video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUzI95mmbwA
I am just wondering if anyone on here could be kind enough to help me on this small problem as it is for my school project and I am not sure how to fix it.

GameManager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject platformPrefab;

    public int platformCount = 300;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3();

        for (int i = 0; i < platformCount; i++)
        {
            spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(.5f, 2f);
            spawnPosition.x += Random.Range(-5f, 5f);
            Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Game Hierarchy]

[image: GameManager script is on game manager]

[Platforms being close together issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usgxl.png)

Comment: You show us the code which moves your player ... it doesn't show how platforms are spawned which seems to be the subject of your question ... also there are no screenshots here ;)

Comment: hey, that is the platform code but if needed I can provide the player movement code, camera follow code and game manager code as well. Also sadly I'm not able to add images since I don't meet the reputation requirements`

Comment: Again: for the issue you are asking about which seems to be related to how the platforms are generated we don't really care what code is on the platform itself, since this code is not what influences the platforms position ;) Show us the code which is generating the platforms and how hey are positioned

Comment: I have updated my original post with all the scripts used, and hopefully some helpful screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

So you generate your platforms using

```
void Start ()
{
    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3();

    for (int i = 0; i < platformCount; i++)
    {
        spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(.5f, 2f);
        spawnPosition.x += Random.Range(-5f, 5f);
        Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

which basically means that the next platform always has an offset to the one before in a range `+/- 5`.

This means however, that the next value would always have to counterbalance the current offset in order to be fully balanced in total. Since you use a **random** and not an equal distribution thiis is not guaranteed!

In order to make sure platforms don't get "skewed" to one side infinitely I would simply make sure they still "fit into the screen" and clamp the position accordingly like e.g.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject platformPrefab;
    public int platformCount = 300;

    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

    // Adjust via the Inspector in order to also take platform width into account!
    public float platformWidth;

    [Min(0)] public float xRange = 5f;

    float minX;
    float maxX;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;

        // get the screen boarders in world space
        minX = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, -mainCamera.transform.position.z)).x + platformWidth / 2f;
        maxX = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, 0, -mainCamera.transform.position.z)).x - platformWidth / 2f;

        Vector3 spawnPosition = Vector3.zero;

        for (int i = 0; i < platformCount; i++)
        {
            spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(.5f, 2f);
            spawnPosition.x += Random.Range(-xRange, xRange);

            // now simply clamp the x position so the platform 
            // doesn't go over the screen boarders
            spawnPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(spawnPosition.x, minX, maxX);

            Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

You could of course also instead of only clamping the position actively counter balance the range and shift it left or right accordingly like e.g.

```
Vector3 spawnPosition = Vector3.zero;

for (int i = 0; i < platformCount; i++)
{
    spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(.5f, 2f);

    var min = -5f;
    var max = 5f;

    var distanceToLeftBorder = spawnPosition.x - minX;
    var distanceToRightBorder = maxX - spawnPosition.x;

    if(distanceToLeftBorder < xRange)
    {
        min += xRange - distanceToLeftBorder;
        max += xRange - distanceToLeftBorder;
    }
    else if(distanceToRightBorder < xRange)
    {
        min -= xRange - distanceToRightBorder;
        max -= xRange - distanceToRightBorder;
    }

    spawnPosition.x += Random.Range(min, max);

    // now simply clamp the x position so the platform 
    // doesn't go over the screen boarders
    spawnPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(spawnPosition.x, minX, maxX);

    Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

---

To your final issue the platforms being too close I would take yet another different approach:

Instead of randomly place at offset +/- 5 rather separate the sign from the distance and do

```
var sign = Mathf.Sign(Random.value);
var distance = Random.Range(platformWidth + SPACING, maxDistance);
spawnPosition.x += distance * sign;
```

which would make sure that the next platform is at minimum the platform width plus an optional spacing (both positive!) and not any closer to the current platform.

I would then instead of clamping simply check if you would hit the border and switch the sign like

```
var sign = Mathf.Sign(Random.value);
var distance = Random.Range(platformWidth + SPACING, maxDistance);

if(spawnPosition.x + distance * sign < minX || spawnPosition.x + distance * sign > maxX)
{
    sign *= -1;
}

spawnPosition.x += distance * sign;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the very issue I had.
I was just wondering, if it's fine with you, how would I change the gap in between each platform. Since I think they are a little close together personally. 
I will provide the image of platforms in a new edit of my original post :D

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it!

Comment: @mastem66 see bottom of the answer anyway ;)